# upload photos through mobile device

Tags: asp.net, iphone, vb.net, upload

I'm planning to let my site users upload photos through their mobile devices specifically Iphone.Currently, they can only upload photos through their desktop or laptop.What would be the best approach using ASP.NET 3.5 and Visual Basic?Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Write a web service which accepts photos and write a client on the iPhone which sends to your web service.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone doesn't support uploading files to web sites (`<input type="file">` just plain doesn't work).

You'll need to either make an actual iPhone app that sends files to your site, or set up a system that allows users to e-mail in their photos to a unique e-mail address associated with their account (Flickr is a nice example of this).